# Calling Haskell from Java with C in between

Tags: java, c, linux, haskell, ubuntu

This probably sounds like a nightmare, but I'd really like to get this working. I am using this example for the most part: [Calling C from Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C) and am trying to get this working on ubuntu.

I am running this in java:

```
package test;

public class JniTest {
    public native int fib(int x);
}
```

this in c after creating the .h file with javah: (test_JniTest.c)

```
#include "test_JniTest.h"
#include "Safe_stub.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_test_JniTest_fib(JNIEnv * e, jobject o, jint f)
{
  return fibonacci_hs(f);
}
```

and then for reference in haskell (before stub): (Safe.hs)

```
module Safe where

import Foreign.C.Types

fibonacci :: Int -> Int
fibonacci n = fibs !! n
    where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
fibonacci_hs = fromIntegral . fibonacci . fromIntegral

foreign export ccall fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
```

and this is what i'm trying to compile it with:

> ghc -c -O Safe.hs

followed by:

> ghc -shared -o libTest.jnilib -optc-O test_JniTest.c
>   -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include/linux

and I am getting this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: test_JniTest.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against
>   undefined symbol `fibonacci_hs' can not be used when making a shared
>   object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am not a c expert by any means and have no idea what to do about this. I tried compiling various ways with -fPIC, but I kept on getting the same error. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the C code have to start the Haskell runtime somewhere?  I think you will need to get that into the code somewhere, either on the C side or the Java side.

Comment: Did you consider using JNA ( https://github.com/twall/jna#readme ) instead of JNI?

Comment: I've answered that one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370177/communication-between-java-and-haskell/10370902#10370902

Comment: @SamuelAudet Hey, can you add that as an answer? I'd be happy to accept that if you post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I've pretty much answered this question here: [Communication between Java and Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370177/communication-between-java-and-haskell), since this issue is more about the error itself, I will be adding the details for that here. The issue stems from Haskell not supporting shared libraries very well, while Java requires them.
[Buildings plugins as Haskell shared libs](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/30) gives us this insight and workaround:

> In principle you can use -shared without -dynamic in the link step. That would mean to statically link the rts all the base libraries into your new shared library. This would make a very big, but standalone shared library. However that would require all the static libraries to have been built with -fPIC so that the code is suitable to include into a shared library and we don't do that at the moment.
>
> If we use ldd again to look at the libfoo.so that we've made we will notice that it is missing a dependency on the rts library. This is problem that we've yet to sort out, so for the moment we can just add the dependency ourselves:
>
> ```
> $ ghc --make -dynamic -shared -fPIC Foo.hs -o libfoo.so \
>  -lHSrts-ghc6.11 -optl-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ghc/lib/ghc-6.11/
> ```

This is a workaround because it requires us to know the version of the rts library at build time.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to actually get something done (as opposed to just playing around with JNI) I suggest tackling this as a garden variety RPC problem and utilizing one of the many framework/protocols for it:

[Protocol Buffers from Google](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

[Thrift from Facebook](http://thrift.apache.org/)

[Avro (well this is mostly a wire protocol)](http://avro.apache.org/)

From what you are trying to do, Thrift might be your best bet since it describes a full client/server RPC stack but I'm pretty sure any of them would pretty much work over a simple socket.