# ghc 7.4.1 not producing stub.o files

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi, haskell-platform

I'm running the default installation of Haskell platform on Ubuntu and when I run this example http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C "ghc -c -O Safe.hs" is not producing the Safe_stub.o file. I have checked this on a separate installation of Ubuntu on a friends box and on both 32 bit and 64 bit Ubuntu installs.

Can somebody confirm if this is specific to ghc-7.4.1 or Ubuntu installs only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a ghc-7.4 (`ghc >= 7.2` actually) thing. That doesn't need and produce `*_stub.o` (or `*_stub.c`) files anymore. However, the command line for the final compilation has to change

```
$ ghc -no-hs-main -optc-O test.c Safe.o  -o test
```

You have to tell GHC that the `main` is not a haskell call.

Comment: Good to know, I was on #haskell irc and a user said it was still in the specifications and that the stub might have just been redirected. Thanks, when I get around to it, i'll update the haskell wiki to reflect this.