# How can I integrate a Haskell DLL into a C++/Qt Windows application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, haskell

I wrote some functions in Haskell and I’d like to build them into a DLL so I can call them from my C++ application. I’m having just an awful time. (It seems like calling a C DLL from Haskell is much more common and better documented.)

My Haskell setup is MinGHC 7.10.1 (32-bit). The C++ project uses Visual Studio 2010 and Qt 5.4; I use qmake to generate the VS project file from a .pro file.  Here’s what I’m doing:

1. Use cabal-install to install the packages my library needs. (These get installed globally, not in a sandbox.)
2. Run `ghc -no-hs-main -v SpectrumMath.hs > ghc_output 2>&1` to dump GHC’s verbose build output to a file.
3. Look at the `ghc_output` file and find the linker command (it’s the line after “*** Linker:”). Extract the library directories (indicated by the `-L` flag) and the library names (indicated by the `-l` flag).
4. Add these libraries to the Qt .pro file, e.g.

   ```
   LIBS += \
       -Lsome_long_path_here \
       -Lsome_other_long_path_here \
       -lsome_library_name_here \
       -lsome_other_library_name_here
   ```
5. Run `ghc --print-libdir`. Append `/include` to the end of this path and add it to the .pro file:

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/MinGHC-7.10.1/ghc-7.10.1/lib/include"
   ```
6. Run qmake to generate a Visual Studio project.
7. Open the VS project. Open the project’s properties and navigate to Configuration Properties → Linker → Input and edit the Additional Dependencies field. Qmake helpfully “fixed” the libraries’ names, so replace each instance of “HS*something*.lib” with “libHS*something*.a”. Likewise, rename “Cffi-6.lib” to “libCffi-6.a” and “HSrts.lib” to “libHSrts.a”.

This crazy process comes from [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/FFI_complete_examples#When_main_is_in_C.2B.2B) on the wiki. It assumes that the C++ file will `#include "SpectrumMath_stub.h"`, a file that was generated by GHC in step 2.

I get stuck at this point because I don’t know what to do with the m library (the one that came from the `-lm` flag). Visual Studio can’t find an “m.lib” but if I remove that library from the list I get dozens of “unresolved externals” messages, so that library *is* needed. How do I tell Visual Studio about the libm dependency? Or should I be following another process entirely?

Comment: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html

Comment: @TheInternet Those instructions mention linking in “Adder\_stub.o”, which is [not even produced by recent versions of GHC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10983869/371228). The instructions are out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `cabal-install` (or `stack`) for this actually. If you plan on distributing this DLL without LPGL-compatible licensing, you likely want to use a build of GHC using `integer-simple` instead of `integer-gmp` (the default).

---

### Haskell side

First, be familiar with [this GHC tutorial](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html).

After reading that, you'll realize you need a copy of `StartEnd.c` somewhere. Let's say it's in `src\`.

So here's your `MyLibrary.cabal` file:

```
...other cabal stuff...

library
  exposed-modules:     MyModule
  --other-modules:
  other-extensions:    ForeignFunctionInterface
  build-depends:       base
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  c-sources:           src/StartEnd.c  --tells cabal to rebuild if this changes
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  --default-extensions:

  -- Add whatever options you need, in addition to these:
  -- (In my experience, adding `-threaded` can make the DLL 
  --  behave better during debugging; but that's only a guess.)
  ghc-options:         -O1 -shared src/StartEnd.c
```

Now build it with `cabal build` (or `stack build` if you're using `stack`).

*Expect to see warnings. Cabal is not quite cognizant of what you're up to.*

You will find three files important to you, relative to your cabal project:

- `HSdll.dll`
- `HSdll.dll.a` (Windows calls these `.lib` files normally; you can rename it if you like)
- `build\...\MyLibrary_stub.h`

**Note that this DLL statically links all Haskell dependencies. So you don't need to tell Visual Studio about anything besides your DLL.**

---

### C++ side

- In your C++ code, you need to include the `MyLibrary_stub.h` file generated above.
- You will also need to include prototypes of `HsStart` and `HsEnd` somewhere:

  `extern "C" {
    void HsStart();
    void HsEnd();
  }`
- The `_stub.h` file includes some GHC headers, so you need to add a folder to your "Additional Includes" in the VS project: `<ghc-folder>\ghc-7.10.1\lib\include`.

  - One trick to doing this is to run `where ghc`, drop `ghc.exe`, and append `\..\lib\include` to the result of that.

In your C++ app, make sure you call `HsStart()` and `HsEnd()` at the beginning and end of your program. I like to encapsulate those in an RAII structure so I can't forget to do it right.

---

#### My experience

I've tried this with `cabal-install` 1.2* versions and `stack`. I've used both GHC 7.8.4 and 7.10.1, each with 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Please note that `Cabal` is soon to come out with [much better support for this](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/2540).

---

#### Naming your DLL

Until Cabal has better support, the only way I've found to give your DLL a name is by adding `-o MyLibrary.dll` to `ghc-options`. Even though it works, GHC gives you warnings when you do this that show it doesn't really know what's going on. To help it out, you can pre-build `StartEnd.c` into `StartEnd.o` and link that instead. The command to use is something like this:

```
cabal exec -- ghc -optc-O -c src/StartEnd.c -o obj/StartEnd.o
```

Now, in `ghc-options`, replace `src/StartEnd.c` with `obj/StartEnd.o`.

*Replacing `cabal` with `stack` should work as well, if you're using `stack`.*

Comment: This seems to work except that my C++ code can’t see the declarations of `HsStart` and `HsEnd`. Should those be in “MyLibrary\_stub.h”?

Comment: I wrote a header file “StartEnd.h”, put in the declarations of `HsStart` and `HsEnd`, and added it to my C++ project. Now everything links and compiles nicely… but I still get [this weird error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31416185/371228). Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need to prototype those in your code. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: If it's helpful, I've been using Visual Studio 2013 for this without any issues. It seems that there might be a bug in VS 2010 (from your other SO question)?