# JavaCPP, UnsatisfiedLinkError when native library is archived in JAR

Tags: jar, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, javacpp

I'm trying to call Haskell code from Java, using [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) to help create the necessary JNI binding,  as already discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370177/communication-between-java-and-haskell).

This is how I'm using it:

```
<rootdir>
  /javacpp.jar
  /build (destination of libraris)
  /src   (contains Haskell code)
  /com/example/HSCode.java (Java class to load and use native lib)
```

Content of `HScode.java`:

```
package com.example;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

@Platform(include={"<HsFFI.h>","HScode_stub.h"})
public class HScode {
    static { Loader.load(); }
    public static native void hs_init(int[] argc, @Cast("char***") @ByPtrPtr PointerPointer argv);
    public static native String code_hs(String text);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        hs_init(null, null);
        String s1 = code_hs(s);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Compilation:

```
cd <rootdir>
ghc --make -isrc -dynamic -shared -fPIC src/HScode.hs \
     -o build/libHScode.so -lHSrts-ghc7.8.4 -optl-Wl,-rpath,.
javac -cp javacpp.jar com/example/HScode.java
java -jar javacpp.jar -d build \
     -Dplatform.compiler=ghc -Dplatform.includepath="src:com/example" \
     -Dplatform.compiler.output="-optl-Wl,-rpath,. -optc-O3 -Wall build/libHScode.so -dynamic -fPIC -shared -lstdc++ -lHSrts-ghc7.8.4 -o " com.example.HScode
```

Following this approach, I can create a `libHScode.so` and a `libjniHScode.so` using `javacpp`, which runs fine with:

```
$ java -cp javacpp.jar:. com.example.HScode
```

### Jar

Now, the following step is that I want to package everything in a jar, and be able to use this jar's `com.example.HScode` from a larger java project.

JavaCPP's page mentions:

> [...] Moreover, at runtime, the Loader.load() method automatically
>   loads the native libraries from Java resources, which were placed in
>   the right directory by the building process. **They can even be archived
>   in a JAR file, it changes nothing**. Users simply do not need to figure
>   out how to make the system load the files.

So I thought this should work.

However, if I make a jar `HScode.jar` out of the content of the `build`  folder above, so that my jar contains both `libjniHScode.so` and `libHScode.so`, and run it with:

```
$ java -cp javacpp.jar:HScode.jar:. com.example.HScode
```

then it cannot find my native code (exception edited for anonymization):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniHScode in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:597)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:438)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
    at com.example.HScode.<clinit>(HScode.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /compilation-path/linux-x86_64/libjniHScode.so: HScode.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:580)
```

What am I missing? Does anyone know whether JavaCPP can actually find the native code when it's archived in a jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building for the native libraries by calling `javacpp -jar javacpp.jar com.example.HScode` outputs them in `com/example/linux-x86_64/` automatically and the `Loader` loads them from there. So when building the native libraries by some other means, they still need to be moved to `com/example/linux-x86_64/`, whether inside a JAR file or outside as normal files, if we want the `Loader` to find them.

Comment: Thanks, I guess during your reply, I was editing my question to remove unnecessary stuff and include details about compilation. can the fact that I use `-d build` to move created libraries in a "clean" folder be a problem?

Comment: @cornuz You could use `Loader.load(URL[] urls, String libnameversion)` with `URL`'s from `ClassLoader.getResource()` if that's want you want though.

Comment: your remark about keeping the same structure in the jar makes totally sense. I'd like to try and use the standard Loader. Now the jar contains `com/example/linux-x86_64/libjniHScode.so`. I still don't know where to place the native lib `libHScode.so` inside the jar. I tried both in `com/example/linux-x86_64/` and in the root. No luck. But it *does* work when the native lib is outside the jar, where I invoke `java -cp javacpp.jar:HScode.jar:. com.example.HScode`.

Comment: @cornuz To get extracted, it needs to be part of the `@Platform` annotation either as `link="HScode"` or `preload="HScode"`.

Comment: Indeed, the `link` annotation makes it work, thanks! I was assuming it to be equivalent to using `-Dplatform.link="HScode"`. Using only the latter makes the `-copylibs` option work, but doesn't make the lib get extracted from the jar at runtime.