# Javacpp: Unable to link shared library inside a jar

Tags: javacpp

I'm trying to link a jar archived with the shared library and the javacpp generated jni shared library. Is that doable?

I have 3 jar
- javacpp.jar
- lib.jar (.h file, libCube.so, libjniJavaCube.so)
- Cube.jar (classes)

I have no problem running the problem when I dropped the shared libraries on the same level as my jars. However, I can't seem to be able to link them when they are packed in a jar. Thoughts anyone?

I read this link [JavaCPP, UnsatisfiedLinkError when native library is archived in JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978732/javacpp-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-native-library-is-archived-in-jar) but Samuel is a little vaue on the "link" parameter and how to link if libraries are packed in jar. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, but there is a proposal here that would make this possible: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/pull/43

Please consider making a contribution by helping out!